# getControlPointAtIndex parameter type

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I am reading iOS Core Animation Advanced Techniques.

In this book there is an example code that gets control points from a CAMediaTimingFunction:

```
//create timing function
CAMediaTimingFunction *function = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:1 :0 :0.75 :1];

//get control points
CGPoint controlPoint1, controlPoint2;
[function getControlPointAtIndex:1 values:(float *)&controlPoint1]; 
[function getControlPointAtIndex:2 values:(float *)&controlPoint2];
```

The controlPoint value that I get seems to be wrong:

```
controlPoint1   CGPoint (x = 5.2635442471208903E-315, y = 4.9406564584124654E-324)  
controlPoint2   CGPoint (x = 0.0078125018408172764, y = 2.8421186829703262E-314)
```

However, if I use an float array as type of the parameter `values`, I get the right values of controlPoint:

```
float c1p[2], c2p[2];
[function getControlPointAtIndex:1 values:c1p];
[function getControlPointAtIndex:2 values:c2p];
```

The values are:

```
controlPoint1   CGPoint (x = 1, y = 0)  
controlPoint2   CGPoint (x = 0.75, y = 1)
```

The question is, how can I use CGPoint as the first code snippet shows? Why isn't it getting the right values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are showing is the book code, the book code is wrong. `functionWithControlPoints:` takes *float* values. CGPoint is made up of *CGFloat* values. They are not the same - as you have discovered. You can get these values using an array of float, as you are doing.

(I suppose the first code would work on a 32-bit device, where CGFloat and float *are* the same. But that is sort of an accident. To try to treat two floats as a CGPoint is just silly.)

Comment: Thank you, that clears my doubts. The first code actually works when I build it with 32-bit architecture.